# Pig not working in oozie launcher

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

In my cluster contain:

- Hadoop 2.5
- Pig 0.15
- Oozie 4.2

I builded oozie with command:

```
bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests -Dhadoop.version=2.3.0 -Dpig.version=0.15.0
```

I submmited job to oozie to call the pigscript:

```
A = load '/data.txt' using PigStorage('/t');
store A into '/output' USING PigStorage();
```

But i got the warning:

```
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl  - falling back to default JobControl (not using hadoop 0.20 ?)
```

And then is the error:

```
Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
```

If i run pig standalone like this:

```
pig test.pig
```

It worked.

Can you tell me what were wrong? Why Jobcontrol fall back hadoop, and then require class instead in interface ?

Sorry my english is bad.

Comment: Can you provide `pig` action you are using to execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

Please recompile the pig for Hadoop Verion like below:

```
$ant clean jar-withouthadoop -Dhadoopversion=2.5
```

and check the status.
Reference [URL](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201310.mbox/%3C20131025161130.GK24790@localhost%3E) hope mention steps will guide you to fixthe Problem.

Comment: I was copied oozie from working system for my develop cluster and it's working.
above error was caused by oozie, not pig